# Calibre to Kindle Book Transfer

Tags: kindle, pdf, calibre, fonts

I just bought a Kindle Paperwhite. I am having troubles transferring books from calibre to Kindle. The major problems that I face are as follows:

1. Font size even after changing the PDF format to either MOBI or AZW3 format remains so small that I am not able to read the book.
2. Whenever I transfer books from Calibre to Kindle, the dictionary disappears every time. I have downloaded the dictionary five times so far.

Could somebody help me with that?

Comment: Those are two disjunct questions, you should split them up.

Answer (score 4):

Increasing font size and spacing is a frequent problem for PDFs, especially for tablets that are 6 inch. PDFs are supposed to be printable documents, and so font size and other things tend to be fixed proportionate to the document size.

Merely converting to .mobi will not solve this.

If your original book were .epub, this is less likely to be a problem because it is based on HTML which is reflowable.

My recommendation is to try to read the PDF on a mobile PDF app instead of doing another conversion. Also, the larger the tablet size, the easier the PDF will be to read anyway. I have a 9 inch device where PDFs are generally easy to read.

Another idea (if you are desperate) is to try to copy the text in the PDF to a MS Word file, and then do the conversion from MS Word. Those kinds of conversions tend to produce significantly better results in Calibre.

Answer (score 1):

Don't know if you have found other solutions for the issue you posted earlier.
there is a way to convert change the pdf for your device. try  [k2pdf](http://www.willus.com/k2pdfopt/)  application. it'll allow you to change the PDF/ebook to match with the your paperwhite's screen (mode cp and -dev kv or -dev kp3) will convert them suitable for viewing for the screen.

You also can use the font size customization within calibre the set of font sizes need to specified at the time of conversion. but the text reflow is horrible with calibre. (Each line will becomes paragraph).

Another solution is using the mobicreator.. but doesn't work well for tables in pdf.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to go for [Sendtokindle](https://www.amazon.com/gp/sendtokindle) software for windows os which converts and sends the pdf into kindle server directly so that once you connected to the network it will be automatically downloaded where you can change the font.